# Automatic workflow service to process Google Drive files?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation, google-drive-api, workflow

Is there any free services where I can monitor Google Drive with filename pattern,and identify newly created/modified file and process it using a Python script, and update Google Sheets accordingly?

Comment: You may want to read these [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) quickstarts. Both services are free up to a certain [limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#:~:text=This%20version%20of%20the%20Google,is%20no%20daily%20usage%20limit.).

Comment: But where can I run the code using APIs? I don't have a 24x7 running server to schedule jobs to process.

Comment: Can you clarifyu with more detail what you are trying to do? Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)